# Where is documentation for prior releases of maven-release-plugin? I'm looking for version 2.8.2

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to find out if the maven-release-plugin uses the string `release.arguments` or `arguments` to pass additional arguments to the maven release plugin.  For example,

```
mvn release:perform -DignoreSnapshots=true -Drelease.arguments=-DaltDeploymentRepository=my-login::default::https://nexus.example.com/repository/maven-releases/
```

I found the latest release at https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html which at the time of this question is 3.0.0-M4.  The current version uses `arguments` and it's documented.

My question is:

**Does Maven have a standard way of storing/referring to previous releases of plugins?**  If not, what is a way to get the list of arguments available in the 2.8.2 version?

Many sites have a dropdown that lets you pick the prior versions, but I didn't see that on this website or this plugin.

### Looking for the solution

A search of the above question did not find anything useful.  A search on SO found several questions but none that answered my question, see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmaven%5D+release+plugin

- [maven release plugin - manipulating project release version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43065612/maven-release-plugin-manipulating-project-release-version)
- [Accesing release version of maven-release-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49418837/accesing-release-version-of-maven-release-plugin)
- Several others questions, that I won't list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the parameters has as "since" column.

There you can see that `arguments` was always called `arguments`.

Comment: Hum, I wonder where I read that it was called `release.arguments`.  Thanks for the answer.